# Css best practice for applying similar styling

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I am implementing css for my MVC 5 application. I have a question regarding what is the best practice when applying styles to similar controls which may vary in few properties  but may have others in common. In my application I would be creating several kendo grids. The width varies but the rest are same.

```
#grid {
    margin-top:80px;
    vertical-align:central;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;

}

#teamGrid {
    margin-top:80px;    
    vertical-align:central;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:900px;
}
```

**UI**

```
<div id="teamGrid"></div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        var teams = [
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 },
            { CountryCode: "GB", TeamName: "T1", TeamDescription: "Team1", IsActive: 1 }
        ];

        var teamDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: teams, pageSize: 20, sort: { field: "TeamName", dir: "asc" } });
        teamDataSource.read();

        $("#teamGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: teamDataSource,
            columns: [
                { field: "CountryCode", title: "Country Code", width:"50px" },
                { field: "TeamName", title: "Team Name", width: "50px" },
                { field: "TeamDescription", title: "Team Description", width: "70px" },
                { field: "IsActive", title: "Active", width: "50px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: "100px" }
            ],

            scrollabe:false,
            pageable: true,
            sortable:true,
            //groupable: true,
            filterable: true,
            editable: (editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup))

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: use "class: instead of "id".

Comment: You can not ask for best practices or preferences because these are individual decision and does not narrow down a question field.

Comment: Try pointing to a coding problem for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class to set attributes to all **.grids**
You have to set class `.grids` to **#grid** and **#teamGrid**

```
.grids{
    margin-top:80px;
    vertical-align:central;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

#grid {

}

#teamGrid {
    width:900px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry did you mean create both class and ids and assign both to the grids. Is that what you are saying ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that is set

Comment: Where you have the id's #grid and #teamGrid, add a class to that div (in the html). The class must be .grids, then declare the css class like i put in the answer. Or just put the html code and i tell you where.

Comment: Updated the post with UI

Comment: That is just one kendo Grid... you said severals kendo Grid. But well, you need to create the div like that <div class="grids" id="teamGrid"></div>